# AutomaticInputSessionShutdown Custom Session Shutdown Handler

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, service, host

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.dispatcher.dispatchruntime.automaticinputsessionshutdown.aspx), I see that it says the following:

> If you set the AutomaticInputSessionShutdown property to false, the
>   channel must be closed by some other mechanism. In this case, you must
>   add a custom session shutdown handler to the
>   InputSessionShutdownHandlers property.

What are the consequences if you don't add a custom session shutdown handler to the InputSessionShutdownHandlers property and set the AutomaticInputSessionShutdown property to false? I have two WCF services, and they can only connect to each other, secured by certificates, and I do not want their session to ever die.

Comment: Memory management might become an issue sooner or later. Is creating the services as Singleton instances an option? Presumably the reason why you don't want to session to die is because you want to maintain some state between your services that spans over multiple transactions. I would look at changing your instance mode or fining some other mechisms for managing state, rather than messing around with lower lever configuration settings such as AutomaticInputSessionShutdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alexandru,

The whole purpose of the `InputSessionShutdown` is to allow the service to make a final response to the client indicating that the client can close it's connection.

From your description, the "client" in this case is another one of your services.  As long as the "client" service can properly shutdown if the duplex session is terminated, there shouldn't be any consequence for not providing a custom `InputSessionShutdownHandler`.